# Adding a New Sibling Div in HTML Doesn't put it in the Bottom?

Tags: html, css, position

Please ignore the random image that doesn't exist. My question is why is the blue "credits div" element on the same line as the "h2" elements. Usually when I add a new div, it goes straight to the bottom of the page. I have checked a bunch of times and the "credits div" is a sibling of the "bottom div", so it is supposed to be on a new line right? How can I make credits  go to the bottom?

```css
body {
  margin:  auto;
  max-width: 960px;
}
h1{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: normal;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.bottom{
  position: relative;
}
.sakuhin{
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
}
.pink{
  background-color: #D95483;
  height: 16px;
  width: 5px;
  display:inline-block;
}

h2 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
ul.photos{
  width: 75%;
}
ul.photos>li{
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
}
ul.photos>li>img{
  border: 5px solid #fff;
}
.intro{
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 75%
}
p {
  line-height: 1.3;
}
.credits{
  background-color: #6599cb;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>I am a Photographer</h1>
  <div class="bottom">
    <div class="sakuhin">
      <div class="pink"></div>
      <h2>New Photos</h2>
      <ul class="photos">
        <li> <img src="./img/thumb1.jpg"> </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="intro">
      <div class="pink"></div>
      <h2>About Me</h2>
      <p>Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  <div class="credits">
    By Mana<br>
    © Web Creator Box
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by stick the footer to the bottom using `position:fixed;`, `bottom:0;`, `left:0;`. Your code should be:

```
.credits{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    background-color: #6599cb;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it go to the bottom without making it stuck there throughout the whole web page?

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing one of the effects of setting the position of an element to `position:absolute`. Absolutely positioned elements are taken out of the normal flow of the document. This means to other elements in the document, the absolutely positioned element doesn't exist.
In your case both `.intro` and `.sakuhin` elements are taken out of the normal flow since they are absolutely positioned. This makes the `.credits` div to occupy the space it would have, if `.intro` and `.sakuhin` div didn't exist.
You can use `position:relative` instead if you are looking to just move things around for the layout. Using floats is also an option that can be considered.

```css
body {
  margin:  auto;
  max-width: 960px;
}
h1{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: normal;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.sakuhin{
  display: inline-block;
}
.pink{
  background-color: #D95483;
  height: 16px;
  width: 5px;
  display:inline-block;
}

h2 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
ul.photos{
  width: 75%;
}
ul.photos>li{
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
}
ul.photos>li>img{
  border: 5px solid #fff;
}
.intro{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%
}
p {
  line-height: 1.3;
}
.credits{
  background-color: #6599cb;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>I am a Photographer</h1>
  <div class="bottom">
    <div class="sakuhin">
      <div class="pink"></div>
      <h2>New Photos</h2>
      <ul class="photos">
        <li> <img src="./img/thumb1.jpg"> </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="intro">
      <div class="pink"></div>
      <h2>About Me</h2>
      <p>Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  <div class="credits">
    By Mana<br>
    © Web Creator Box
  </div>
</body>
```